# Checkbox is unchecked, but it loads as checked

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, onchange, checked

Some checkbox are loading, with required option. They are not checked at begin.
With 'inputCHKChange' function, we should to update checkbox. So it's update checkbox as it's checked or not.

Problem is checkbox are not checked at begin. but during the load they are checked. How could to manage it?

The html:

```
<fieldset><div class="form-check"><label class="form-check-label"><input onchange="inputCHKChange(this);" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="undefined[]" checked="false" required="">A</label></div><div class="form-check"><label class="form-check-label"><input onchange="inputCHKChange(this);" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="undefined[]" checked="false" required="">B</label></div></fieldset>
```

The script:

```
function inputCHKChange(objInput) {
objInput.setAttribute('checked', objInput.checked);
}
```

Sample on [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/mahma/wypoLd56/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attribute for `checked` is set to `false`:

```
checked="false"
```

Any value in the `checked` attribute, or even the presence of the `checked` attribute, will mark the checkbox as checked. Remove the attribute and the default value of unchecked will be shown.

Example: the `checked` attribute is completely removed.

```html
<div class="form-check">
  <label class="form-check-label">
    <input onchange="inputCHKChange(this);"
           type="checkbox" 
           class="form-check-input" 
           name="undefined[]" 
           required="">A</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the "checked" attribute. It should work fine

Look at the following code

```
<fieldset><div class="form-check"><label class="form-check-label"><input onchange="inputCHKChange(this);" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="undefined[]" checked="false" required="">A</label></div><div class="form-check"><label class="form-check-label"><input onchange="inputCHKChange(this);" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="undefined[]" checked="false" required="">B</label></div></fieldset>
```